# hybridauth basic user database

Tags: database, hybridauth

I'm starting to use hybridauth.github.io to integrate login with FB/Twitter/Google to my site besides the existing regular email/password login.

Is there a basic common fields I should save from these methods or just the email and "login type" would do?

Thank you
Regards